# Prestashop 1.6.1.18 on permanent maintenance mode

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I set my PrestaShop to maintenance mode so as to update it, The update couldn't pull through, so I decide to continue with the same version. Now, I enable the shop but it keeps showing the maintenance mode.

Comment: If you have multistore enable you need to check you enabled the shop in correct context (all shops/ shop group/shop). Also you can go to the table configuration and search by `name` Like PS_SHOP_ENABLE and set all to 1.

Comment: ok let me try that.

Comment: Thanks I went to enable the other shop and it works.